# Is there a Windows 7 compatibility matrix?

Tags: windows-7

When Vista was ramping up for release, I recall a [a website](http://www.iexbeta.com/wiki/index.php/Windows_Vista_Software_Compatibility_List) was organized to document software compatibility with Vista. Is there a similar software compatibility matrix created by community effort for Windows 7?

Comment: Of what compatibility are you speaking?  Prior versions?  Hardware?

Comment: Good point. Software compatibility.

Comment: Sorry that this isn't an answer but your begging a question: I've been running Windows7 for months now, installing all kinds of various open source softwares, scanners, drivers, etc. and haven't had a problem with a single piece of software. I'd say the odds are LOW that you would run into a problem. Your more likely to be hit by lightning.

Comment: I've already discovered that VMWare vSphere client is not windows 7 compatible. I expect that will improve but with the release fast approaching one would hope they'd be on the ball.

Comment: There is a workaround for that, it is listed about 2/3 down http://communities.vmware.com/thread/211440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft claims that if it runs under Vista, it should run under Windows 7.  If you have any particular concerns, I would look at the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit 5.5 available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a published document, but you can use the [Windows 7 Upgrade advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx).  You can run it on a machine and it will report on software / hardware compatability.